# Should I care about licensing any of my contributions on SO?

Tags: support, mit-license

In particular, why should I specifically note that I explicitly choose NOT to license any of my contributions under MIT license (or any other terms, for that matter)?

Comment: What do you mean? You don't have a *choice* of whether your contributions get licensed. All contributions here are automatically licensed according to our terms.

Comment: Isn't this something that is discussed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange?

Comment: @animuson The question arose when I saw an explicit statement declaring that every contribution of an user is under some other license, which was required by him

Comment: Users are not allowed to modify the terms or license of the content they contribute here on Stack Overflow. They are perfectly welcome to release their contributions under an *additional* license if they'd like, but it will always be available under *our* license as well.

Comment: @animuson Here is what I read: _"Copyright notice: I license the code snippets I authored AND posted as part of any of my answers on stackoverflow.com under the GNU General Public License version 3.0 or Creative Commons Attribution license required by Stack Overflow at your option.

In particular, please note that unless specifically noted by me otherwise, I explicitly choose NOT to license any of my contributions under MIT license (or any other terms, for that matter)."_ and got me confused.

Comment: Yes, so they're not doing anything wrong. The MIT license does not go into effect until February 1, 2016, and we cannot force past contributions to change their licensing terms. However, the user will not have any choice for any contributions they make past February 1, 2016 as the new license will be a part of our terms of service past that date.

Comment: @animusons comment sums up half of the reason there's a severe back-blow to SE considering changing their terms to a dismembered MIT crayon-license for code. The other half it being a dismembered crayon-license.

Comment: I just thought that everything here is public domain / license free, but I guess I should inform myself more...on the other hand the how is the so called MIT license different than a license free?

Comment: @simplicisveritatis: What is "a license free"? Do you mean "public domain" / not protectable by copyright at all? Or do you mean an ultra-permissive license? No license, if copyrightable, means all rights reserved. You might want to read the post rene linked.

Comment: @Deduplicator I am reading it, thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MIT license is literally as simple as you can get.

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software... (continues on)

Basically, you let anyone take the code, modify, merge, publish, make money, and even relicense it, provided that the copyright notice is present be included in all portions of the software, and that the original authors are not liable in any way.

There is a lot of information present here in this question [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com): [Ramifications of the proposed new SE licensing model](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/ramifications-of-the-proposed-new-se-licensing-model).

---

Note that any code contributions you made while the TOS is effective will be made under the MIT license, whether you like it or not.

Comment: The last sentence is actually misleading. The MIT licence needs to be issued by a person who has the rights to do so; SO doen’t, which is why it needs that licence to be issued by the contributor. The content won’t automatically become MIT licenced even if the contributor refuses (or doesn’t himself even have the right). All that *can* happen is that the content is illegal and must be removed and the contributor gets banned for ToS violation. ToS are no magic licence grant, no matter how much one wants this. (They aren’t fully enforceable anyway.)

Comment: @mirabilos Oh. So your text isn't under a Creative Commons license? Of course it is. If you think I'm wrong, ask a question at either Law SE or Open Source SE.

Comment: my text is under SO’s “CC-WIKI” because I choose to publish it under that licence, not because SO’s ToS say so. If I choose not to, I’m violating the ToS, but that nevertheless gives *nobody* the right to use the text under CC-WIKI.

Comment: @mirabilos Even if you didn't want to, you wouldn't have a choice: *You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license.* from the ToS. You accepted these terms when you created an account, and affirmed them when you made a post. Sorry, but you don't have a case here. If you don't want that license, *then don't use the site.* ToS are enforceable, and there is case law to support it.

Comment: I never said it was me that didn’t, so **stop being so offensive**, thanks. Yes, ToS are enforceable, but if someone refuses to do something as onerous as issue licences (or cannot, because they don’t have the right in the first place), the enforcement is *not* forcing the licence but breaking the ToS (hence, account termination). The content would then *still* be illegal.